# Problem in Internet Access using Static Ip connection

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, lan

My computer (running WINDOWS XP) is on the network and can access the internet. It's IP address is set automatically (LAN -> Internet Protocol -> Properties -> Obtain an IP address Automatically).

It works fine with this. Now I wish to use separate line for internet access. So I simply disconnect the network cable and connect the new network cable.

This time my IP address is static (Predefined). So I configured the IP with the specified IP address and gateway. It works for five minute after configuration after which I am unable to access the internet.

After some time it starts working again but the problem is intermittent. When I connect the same cable with same IP address to any other computer system (running WINDOWS XP), it works fine all the time.

I think there is any problem with my computer system what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

A little more about how your network is setup will help.  What kind of router for starters?  What does your ipconfig look like under static and dynamic?

You should also fire up the Event Viewer.  It will be under Administration tools.  Or fire up the run box and type"eventvwr.msc." Windows will log network errors under the System log.  Check under there and they will probably be warning icons.

That's where I would start first.

Comment: This really should be more of a comment as it is clarifying questions, not an answer to his question.

Comment: I did offer an answer.  Event Viewer is the starting point Microsoft suggests in these cases.